# Usage of "requirement"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, usage, word-in-context

I've got the below question from one of my colleagues from the States.

> The question is for A's executives sitting on a board of a foreign
> subsidiary (B) of A, are there supervisory expectations or regulations
> that set forth any *requirements* for that board member to raise any
> issues to the parent(A). APAC Compliance asked what *requirements* there
> are for A's executives sitting on the board of APAC subsidiaries (B) to
> raise issues learned as a board member to the head office (A).

When I saw this question at first, I thought he would like to know what is necessary for A's executives to raise issues of B to A, such as some specific qualification, eligibility or conditions. However, it seems that he would like to know whether A's executives has any obligations (ex. duty to report under the Corporate Law) to raise issues of B to A and if so, what kind of regulations obligate A's executives to do so. From my understanding, "requirement" is a thing that is needed or compulsory. But, in the above usage, the word seems to be used just to substitute for "to require/demand". I mean, to restate what he wanted to say in other words,

> The question is for A's executives sitting on a board of a foreign
> subsidiary of A, are there supervisory expectations or regulations
> that set forth *to require/demand* that board member to raise any issues
> to the parent. APAC Compliance asked what *requires/demands* A's
> executives sitting on the board of APAC subsidiaries to raise issues
> learned as a board member to the head office.

It's a subtle difference, but I'm a little bit confused because the overall meaning of the question could be totally different because the problem here is anything but specific qualification, eligibility or conditions.

Could you please give me a clear explanation for the usage of this word?

Comment: You haven't provided a link to the source, but it's obviously written by a non-native Anglophone, so I don't see much point in us trying to analyse it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to interpret text written by a non-native speaker

Comment: @FumbleFingers The original sentences are below. Maybe it got weird beacuse I editted his original wordings. "The question is for A's executives sitting on a board of a foreign subsidiary of A, are there supervisory expectations or regulations that set forth any requirements for that board member to raise any issues to the parent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "APAC Compliance asked what requirements there are for A's executives sitting on the board of APAC subsidiaries to raise issues learned as a board member to the head office."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd highly appreciate your patience and understanding..!

Comment: This is getting worse! You admit to having edited the original (which inevitably involves you parsing and interpreting the text), then you ask us to interpret *your* text! Presumably your colleague's request came to you as text rather than speech. So please give us the *exact* text (by Cut & Paste or a url link).

Comment: ...and that original text needs to go ***in the question itself***, not a comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My apologies. This is communication inside my company (that's why I'm not able to provide any link), so I wanted to avoid identification. I'm gonna edit the question shortly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Having seen the revised text, I think it's almost 100% certain that your colleague is asking ***under what circumstances*** can / should Company A's executives (sitting on the board of Company B?) tell people in *their own (Company A)* HQ about things they learn while sitting in on Company B board meetings. But this is potentially a legal minefield, so you shouldn't trust *any* interpretations here. If the two companies are commercially separate, they should get lawyers to draw up a mutually agreed (boilerplate?) description of "the rules" for commercially sensitive information disclosure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, my initial interpretation on his question was not so wrong from a native speaker's perspective in general?

Comment: This kind of text isn't suitable for "learning English". Most of what I think comes from having worked for decades as a subcontractor to many different companies, most of whom would have dearly loved to pump me for any information I learned while subcontracting to their rivals! It's a matter of knowing about *commercial relationships*, not *English.*

Comment: Apart from anything else, it's not clear to me why you've mentioned *three* companies (A, B, and APAC). Because of that I'm not sure if your colleague (employed by A?) expects *his own* company to set the rules, or if he assumes Company B dictates to him what he is and isn't allowed to report back to his own HQ. But if he gets it wrong, your colleague could end up in jail!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I really appreciate your comments.  Just like you, I thought at first that he would like to question about such kind of things like confidentiality or any conditions in order for A's executives to disclose the issues of B they learned while sitting in B's board to A. But later I found that he wanted to know whether A's executives are obligated to report such issues to A under any regulations. In that case, I assume the word "requirement" does not mean "a thing that is necessary" but rather "obligation" or just noun version of the verb "require" here.

Comment: Thus I wanted to know if that kind of usage is usual or not from a native speaker's perspective.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry to confuse you, I edited the question above to make it clearer. There are only A and B. B is A's subsidiary in Asia Pacific (APAC).

Comment: So actually, for most "legal" purposes, A and B are *the same company*. Whatever - your colleague (and you, if you might learn things about B from him) should liaise with your line managers to check what's expected, just in case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought "Under what circumstances can they report the issues to A?" and "Are there any obligations for them to report the issues to A?" are totally different, so I'm a bit confused. The usage of the word "requirement" here is not familiar to me. But anyway you're right it actually is a legal matter. Thank you so much for taking your time! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. But I think the question will probably get closed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the Cambridge dictionary explains,](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/requirement), the word "requirement" can mean "an official rule about something that it is necessary to have or to do." That is what "requirement" means in this context; your colleague is asking about the *rules* requiring a board member to report something to A.

Comment: Are they the rules that require a board member to report something to A or the rules when a board member has to comply with when they reports something to A?

Comment: The former; they are rules that require a board member to report something to A.